# How the table span works?

Tags: html, html-table

What I would like to do:
[image]

What did I wrote:

```
<table>
    <TR>
        <TD ROWSPAN="4">left</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="12">middle</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">right</TD>
    </TR>
   <TR>
        <TD ROWSPAN="4">left2</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">right2</TD>
   </TR> 
    <TR>
        <TD ROWSPAN="4">left3</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">right3</TD>
    </TR>
  <TR>
        <TD ROWSPAN="3">right4</TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

It turns out with this:
[image]

I would like the table have same height, I can work in this way, but it is not the same height:

```
 <table>
    <TR>
        <TD>left</TD>
        <TD ROWSPAN="12">middle</TD>
        <TD>right</TD>
    </TR>
   <TR>
        <TD>left2</TD>
        <TD>right2</TD>
   </TR> 
    <TR>
        <TD>left3</TD>
        <TD>right3</TD>
    </TR>
  <TR>
        <TD>right4</TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

and the result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got it! The trick was **having a total of twelve `<tr>`s, even though some of them are empty**.

As a point of curiosity, I solved this by making the table in excel, saving as html, and deleting all of the inline styles that excel puts in there.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=4>left</td>
  <td rowspan=12>middle</td>
  <td rowspan=3>right</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=3>right2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=4>left2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=3>right3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=4>left3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=3>right4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```